# Is it possible to sort items from an external content type?

Tags: bcs, external-content-type, sorting

I have an external list/content type set up that reads data from a SQL database *view*.

I only have access to the one view, I do not have access to any tables directly.

This database has been around for years and has over 50,000 items in it. I need to work with only the most recently modified items.

I asked the DB administrators to apply a sort to the view that would order the items by Modified date, descending, so that the most recently modified items would float to the top.

They said they have done it, but when I go to look at my external list, it looks like everything is still sorted by ID ascending (the database has it's own ID integer field).

I'm trying to ensure that I always have access to the most recently modified items, even though there is a BCS limit of 2000 items returned for a Read List operation.  I figured that if the SQL view on the server was sorted that way, the top 2000 items would always include the most recently modified items.

Is there a way to make the external content type respect the sorting on the SQL view?  Or is there a way to send along `ORDERBY` instructions along with the filter information as part of the Read List operation from the SharePoint side?